# CallInEditor does not seem to modify the dirty state of a UWidget

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I have used the `UFUNCTION` specifier [`CallInEditor`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.2/en-US/function-specifiers/) to modify existing data in a custom `UWidget`. However, the data seems to be reset to the previous state when I hit compile. It also does not mark the object as dirty which is odd, since I changed a `UPROPERTY()`.

The following code illustrates the issue:

```
// .h
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FExampleData
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    float Value = 0.0f;
};

class UExampleWidget : public UWidget
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    UFUNCTION(CallInEditor)
    void SortData();

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    TArray<FExampleData> Data;
};

// .cpp
UExampleWidget::SortData()
{
    Data.Sort([](const FExampleData& a, const FExampleData& b){ return a.Value < b.Value; });
}
```

When I create an instance of the widget in the UMG Editor and then set the values manually, the interface is marked as dirty and I can store the data. When I click on the button "Sort Data", it calls my method and I can see the data being sorted in the Details panel, but does not seem to change the Dirty-State of the object. When I hit compile (which still has a green checkmark), the data is reset to the previous state.

Now my question is: How can I ensure that the editor recognizes the change properly? I already tried calling [`UWidget::Modify()`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/UMG/Components/UWidget/Modify/) before or after the modification, but it doesn't seem to change anything.